# Can I safely remove _vti folders added by my host or cpanel?

Tags: directory, remove, web-server

I notice user accounts on my cpanel server came with some _vti folders installed by default.

1. _vti_bin
2. _vti_cnf
3. _vti_log
4. vti_pvt
5. _vti_txt
6. _private

As I understand these are some kind of Front Page related folders. Is it safe to delete them if I don't user Frontpage? (I am more of a Notepad++ and Winscp fan :) )

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front Page hasn't been in common use in many years, and those files/directories serve no useful purpose that I know of when Front Page isn't in use.

I would consider them safe to delete, though I would also consider shopping for a new hosting provider.